# Microsoft Dynamics 365 bulk update/import via Microsoft Flow

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, power-automate

Is there a way to perform a bulk update from an CSV file into Dynamics 365 via Microsoft Flow?

I have been looking at the following capability that was supposed to be released (September 2019), but could find the "Batch" action anywhere under common data service:

[Automated flows support batch operations in Common Data Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/april19/microsoft-flow/automated-flows-support-batch-operations-common-data-service)

Release notes:

[What's new and planned for Microsoft Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/April19/microsoft-flow/planned-features)

[image]

[image]

However, I was hoping there is an alternative that could even possibly leverage some bulk update task in the mean time.

The requirement is that I would like to perform a bulk update of records once a day, updating/inserting as needed.

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Comment: We ended up loading these files in small batches and processing using Flow. A console app would have worked well but the solution architect on the project did not want any coding done. To add to this, the client did not want to purchase Kingswaysoft for ongoing data integration either. So our hands were tied on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ETL job for Dynamics 365 is huge deal, we have third party providers like Kingswaysoft for SSIS, Scribe, Cozyroc, etc to furnish the necessary connector versions along with rapidly changing CRM endpoints. They support batch operations, multi threading using RESTful web api as well.

Pro developers will do console app & do task schedulers for the same ETL job. Now we want to do the same in MS Flow (Power Automate), surprisingly the links you shared were removed for the trace of those terminologies. Impossible?

We can do read the CSV file & iterate the rows, then transform the values for the datatypes like currency, picklist (optionset), lookup, and finally update/create in Dynamics 365 as per our need.

[Microsoft Flow: CSV Integration with Dynamics 365 (Example)](https://dynamicscitizendeveloper.com/2019/06/06/microsoft-flow-csv-integration-with-dynamics-365/)

Yes, this is not batch operation, but CRM REST web api endpoint supports batch operation, I know to use it only using C# and JavaScript :)